MS Access Form size maximised
In MS Access I have several forms, and when I start them, they are always maximised in size. They take up the whole page, although the design view shows that they should be a lot smaller. I would presume there is a form property that is responsible for the maximising, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I've looked everywhere for this property.
Thanks in advance

Ok, I got it. It was the PopUp property of the form. This needs to be set as yes.
